Can computer algebra system check if the splitting field of two polynomials is same?
I am looking for computer algebra system which checks if the splitting fields of two polynomials over $p$-number field are same or not. At least, knowing their splitting fields are isomorphic will also give me an idea.
In PARI/GP, one can check the Galois of a polynomial upto degree $11$: for example,
P2 = x^9-x+1;
polgalois(P2)

which gives output %3 = [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]  That is, the Galois group is of order $362880$, signature $-1$, and the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_9$.
So given two polynomials up to degree $11$, one can check their Galois group and get some ideas if the splitting fields are equal by looking at their Galois groups.
But how to check the splitting fields/Galois groups of polynomials of degree greater than $11$?
Does SageMath help us?
I found SageMath computing splitting fields of polynomials of degree more than $11$ over number fields. However, I am looking for splitting fields over $p$-adic number fields.
Thanks

Polynomials over which field? Also, do you really mean that the splitting fields are the same - in which sense? Isomorphic?

@MartinBrandenburg,  Given two irreducible polynomials over some $p$-adic number fields (that is, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or its finite extensions), my primary purpose is to check if they generate same splitting field, i.e., if their roots lies in the same field. However, showing the splitting fields are isomorphic at least will give some hints.

By symmetry it seems you the computer to take inputs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and a splitting field $L$ of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and then to output whether or not $L$ splits $g(x)$. Is that right? Perhaps you can provide some more context about this though. Do you have specific polynomials and primes in mind? Or do you want a general purpose and practical method?
